# Using Views Arguments, how do I hide the view results with less than N number of total rows?

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7, Views and Flags to display nodes flagged by a user. I want to be able to hide the results, or use and alternate view display, if the view contains less than N number of results, Let's say 5.

So far I've tried using PHP code to validate my contextual filter:

Contextual filter: Flags:uid
Specify validation code: PHP Code

```
if ($view->total_rows > 5) {
return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Try putting this logic in a template_preprocess_views_view()  function, rather than  in a contextual filter, per this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/hide-a-view-if-less-than-n-results

Comment: Is it not possible to do using PHP and contextual filters? I guess I would accept this as a definitive answer if that's the case. I'm still having trouble making sense of the linked-to answer, as I'm no closer to accomplishing my goal.